# Xcode Swift - How to initialize a 2D array of [[AnyObject]] of as many elements you want

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode, swift

I know I can initialize an array of Ints for example like:

```
var intArray = [Int](count: 10, repeatedValue: 0)
```

What I want to do is something like this:

```
var array = Array(count:6, repeatedValue:Array(count:0, repeatedValue:AnyObject()))
```

(Xcode returns with: AnyObject cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializers)

With the same outcome as I could initialize the array like:

```
var anyObjectArray : [[AnyObject]] = [[],[],[],[],[],[]]
```

But doing the above is ugly if i need like 100 rows of lets say 3

The problem is I can append in my function like:

```
// init array
var anyObjectArray : [[AnyObject]] = [[],[],[]]

//inside a for loop
anyObjectArray[i].append(someValue)
```

That works ok, until of course i gets higher then the number of rows in the array.
A answer to this problem is also acceptable if I could do something like:

```
anyObjectArray[append a empty row here][]
```

But that is probably stupid :)

I hope there is a way to do this cause I don't feel like having a line like:

```
var anyObjectArray : [[AnyObject]] = [ [],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[], ... etc ]
```

at the top of my page ;)

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Just use a for loop to add the internal arrays

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need the second `repeatedValue` initialiser, since you want an empty array.  You can just use

```
var array = Array(count:6, repeatedValue:[AnyObject]())
```

Comment: I did not even get the repeatValue working with the AnyObject. I appears I missed the brackets! 
Thank you for you answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can try with 2 loops, working as a grid :

```
var items: = Array<Array<Item>>()
for col in 0..<maxCol {
    var colItems = Array<Item>()
    for row in 0..<maxRow {
        colItems.append(Item())
    }
    items.append(colItems)
}
//Append as much as you want after
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
let array = Array(count:6, repeatedValue:[])

for (var i=0; i<array.count; i++){
    array[i] = Array(count:0, repeatedValue: AnyObject.self)
}
```

in place of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    let columns = 27
    let rows = 52
    var array = Array<Array<Double>>()
    for column in 0... columns {
        array.append(Array(count:rows, repeatedValue:Int()))
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3:

```
var array = Array(repeating:[AnyObject](),count:6)
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to contribute an answer. It’s because of helpful peers like yourself that we’re able to learn together as a community. Here are a few tips on how to make your answer great: [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Always remember to add explaination to the answer you post, so the users can understand the use of it. @Nithin